# facebook graph api - posting multiple photos

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Graph API to post to a user's timeline

I am using the /me/feed endpoint as documented at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/feed/

From the description, it seems I can only post one photo. Is there a way I can post multiple photos?

On the Facebook site, I can see that multiple photos are supported. But are they supported in API?

Comment: No, you can only post multiple times.

Comment: How did you solve this problem .I am facing with it

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ["Custom Stories" Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph).
Specifically checkout the "Publishing Actions" section [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-actions/v2.0#publish) and notice that the "images" field is designated as allowing "multiple values".

Comment: Read the same thing somewhere. Do you have an example? The documentation is wild.